# MySQL slave I/O thread not running on same server xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, master-slave

Hi I am new in this system.
I tried to implement replication on my server.
For that I tried XAMPP server replication
in my **my.ini** I set like this

For **Master**

```
server-id=6102515
log_bin=mysql-bin
log_error=mysql-bin.err
binlog_do_db=szbasic
```

For **slave**

```
server-id   = 1549363131
replicate-do-db=szbasic1
```

Then I found below picture . from my screenshot.
But i am not getting any value on my **szbasic1** table same as **szbasic**
How can I solve this problem so that I can find same value as master table
Master table = szbasic
slave table = szbasic1

Error log

> 2019-02-06 15:00:42 15100 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'rep@localhost:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000028' at position 359
>
> 2019-02-06 15:00:42 15100 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Fatal error: The slave
> I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids;
> these ids must be different for replication to work (or the
> --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
> Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
>
> 2019-02-06 15:00:42 15100 [Note]
> Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.000028', position
> 359

[image]

[image]

Comment: so what happens when you start the IO thread? What does `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` show?

Comment: having master filtering and slave filtering doesn't automaticly translate the table `szbasic` on the master to `szbasic1` on the slave. `replicate-rewrite-db` from memory is the only translation variable.

Comment: I tried to start IO thread. but it's not starting. SHOW SLAVE STATUS displayed some data but here I found  Last_IO_Error "IO thread stops for fatal error" IO thread not running.